# Undefined variable error message showing up

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display the total number of rows in a table. When I do this following message is displaying in the view, I can't find the mistake in my code. Where is the mistake in the code?

**The error that is displayed**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: data
>   Filename: views/admin_index_view.php
>   Line Number: 15

**Model Function**

```
public function count_registerd_customers() {   
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_customers');
  return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**Controller function**

```
public function index() {
  $data['registered_customers'] = $this->admin_index_model->count_registerd_customers();

  $this->load->view('admin_index_view',$data);
}
```

**On My View**

```
<?php echo $data['registered_customers']; ?>
```

Comment: Try `<?php echo $registered_customers;?>` on your view instead of `<?php echo $data['registered_customers']; ?>`

Comment: For your model another simple way to count result with codeigniter is `return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_customers');`

Comment: hello wolfgang thanks for the response! i have tried your solution but it did not make any difference in the out put.do you see any other faults in my code above?

Comment: Did you load your model on to controller? $this->load->model('admin_index_model'); I cannot see it any where make sure when you have controller that class and file name like Admin_index_model and Admin_index_model.php

Comment: yes,model is there,i think the problem is not in the above code,i will look again,thanks for the help :)